# Compiling TensorFlow custom Op outside of TensorFlow source with GPU kernels

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to compile a custom Op that includes `tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_gpu_kernels.cu.h`. So the top of my GPU kernel file looks as follows:

```
...
#include "tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_gpu_kernels.cu.h"
...
```

I want to compile it in my own repository using `g++` and `nvcc`, so adding the Op to my TensorFlow source installation and compiling it with Bazel is **not** an option. Trying to compile using the instructions given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#compile_the_op_using_your_system_compiler_tensorflow_binary_installation) does not work, as the file is not included by the pip installation package.

I have considered the following solutions:

- 'Hard-coding' the include to a clone of the TensorFlow repo that contains the original source,
- Copying the files from a TensorFlow repo to the TensorFlow installation in my PYTHON_PATH,
- Building a pip package that would include the required files in the pip installation,

but these aren't very appealing workarounds. Is there any other way of doing this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version, there are all files available. In the mean-time I solved it using a CMake + Python

You are basically, writing for all necessary values to configure cmake, like

```
f.write("set(TensorFlow_ABI %i)\n" % tf.__cxx11_abi_flag__)
f.write("set(TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS \"%s\")\n" % tf.sysconfig.get_include())
f.write("set(TensorFlow_LIBRARIES \"%s/libtensorflow_framework.so\")\n" % tf.sysconfig.get_lib())
```

All what is left is just setting the include_directories corre

https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op

When using other kernels, I would just copy the methods into a my operation (never had this case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but copying a specific kernel is not always trivial. The kernel might be calling multiple helper functions from multiple files. It would be a painful and error prone process to look through the whole call stack. Furthermore, the kernels would then have to be maintained by me.

Comment: When writing your own kernel you need to maintain it as well. A TF operation seems to be designed as a stateless operation (can be strategy). If you need another library like Cub, thrust or another kernel from TensorFlow you need to swallow the bitter pill.